# RE: Can't install BASH patch: OSX 10.9.5 update installed, but system still says it is 10.9.4-Still need help

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install, software-update

I have the same problem as described in this previous post:

- [Can't install BASH patch: OSX 10.9.5 update installed, but system still says it is 10.9.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147636/cant-install-bash-patch-osx-10-9-5-update-installed-but-system-still-says-it)

Machine is a MacBook pro, 15-inch early 2011 2GHz Intel Core i7. Now running 10.9.4 - successful download of standalone installer, successful installation - still running 10.9.4. Can't do the bash patch as a result. Checked permissions; rand disk utility to verify the disk. Read console log and got no insight from that either.

What might I need to do to secure my Mac

Comment: Sara - Thanks for posting this. Could you elaborate on what patch you are trying to install - exactly what URL or what version of bash do you expect to end up with? (Just hit the edit button and refine the problem if my initial assumptions were not correct)

Comment: Mike - I am not so concerned about the BASH patch, especially since it has been incorporated into OSX 10.9.5 - I am mainly concerned with the fact that I cannot update OSX, and that my machine goes through all the motions of updating, but the update simply doesn't happen. There are no error messages at all.

Comment: Nothing in /var/log/install.log ? - that would be an unusual case.

Comment: Way too many characters, so must chunk the messages. 1) Oct  9 11:50:38 MacBook-Pro.local Installer[560]: SoftwareUpdate: Adopted /Volumes/OS X 10.9.5 Update Combo/OSXUpdCombo10.9.5.pkg
Oct  9 11:50:38 MacBook-Pro.local softwareupdated (200)[285]: Set products to install at logout  (nowIsLater = FALSE)
Oct  9 11:50:38 MacBook-Pro.local Installer[560]: IFDInstallController 58654700 state = 6
Oct  9 11:50:38 MacBook-Pro.local Installer[560]: Displaying 'Install Succeeded' UI.

Comment: Next: Oct  9 11:50:43 MacBook-Pro.local softwareupdated (200)[285]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=560, uid=502, installAuth=YES rights=(system.install.apple-software, system.install.apple-software.standard-user, system.install.software, com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.modify-settings), transactions=0 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)

Comment: Next: Oct  9 11:50:47 MacBook-Pro.local softwareupdated (200)[285]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=385, uid=502, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeagent)

Comment: I should mention that I bought this Mac secondhand from a guy who deals mainly in PC's & was candid about not knowing Macs very well - I have a hunch that the user identities (esp. the 'main user' identity) were set up strangely.

Comment: One followup: although there are likely ownership/permissions problems due to the machine being used, I did not have any difficulty installing Mavericks, then updating it several times. This is the first time I have had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess from the details provided is that you don't need to apply any patches since Apple has patched bash as part of 10.9.5. If you really aren't on 10.9.5 yet, then keep reading...

Here is what an Apple-patched as of October 8, 2014 Mac should show from terminal:

```
mac:~ mike$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34
mac:~ mike$ which bash &&  `which bash` --version
/bin/bash
GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

(If you are new to terminal, just type the parts after ** mac:~ mike$** so:

```
sw_vers
which bash &&  `which bash` --version
```

After you've compared your values, you can quit the terminal app.

If your versions are not as above, I would delete your update files and start over. Download a new patch from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760 and then open the console app. Look on the left for a toggle button "show log list / hide log list" and show the list. Open the triangle under /var/log and click on install.log - set a marker and then run the installer package.

Watch that log for any errors relating to the manual patch.